# The way for insert and fill table base on column in another table in sql with Several million rows

Tags: sql, t-sql, insert

I have a table similar A With 2 million recordes

```
ROW    ID     ITEM    NoOfUnit
1      1      A       2
2      2      B       1
3      3      C       3
.
.
.
```

I want fill table **B** base on NoOfUnit from **A** Similar to the below

```
ROW    ID      ITEM     QTY
1      1       A        1
2      1       A        1
3      2       B        1
4      3       C        1
5      3       C        1
6      3       C        1
.
.
.
```

Number of rows in table **B** very large and cursor very slow...

Comment: Pease share your attempt

Comment: Did you say "cursor"???

Comment: Please read [this](https://spaghettidba.com/2015/04/24/how-to-post-a-t-sql-question-on-a-public-forum/) for some tips on improving your question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would just use a recursive CTE:

```
with cte as (
      select id, item, NoOfUnit, 1 as n
      from a
      union all
      select id, item, NoOfUnit, n + 1
      from a
      where n < NoOfUnit
     )
insert into b (id, item, qty)
    select id, item, 1
    from cte;
```

If `qty` is ever greater than 100, then you need `option (maxrecursion 0)`.

Answer (score 1):

All you need to do here is duplicate your rows based on the number held in `NoOfUnit`, which you could do with a numbers table.  You then `insert` the result of this into your destination table.

An example of how to do this is as follows:

#### Query

```
declare @d table(ID int, ITEM char(1),NoOfUnit int);
insert into @d values
 (1,'A',2)
,(2,'B',1)
,(3,'C',3)
;

with t as(select t from(values(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1)) as t(t))              -- table with 10 rows
    ,n as(select row_number() over (order by (select null)) as n from t,t t2,t t3,t t4,t t5) -- cross join 10 rows 5 times for 10 * 10 * 10 * 10 * 10 = 100,000 rows with incrementing value
select d.ID
      ,d.ITEM
      ,1 as QTY
from @d as d
    join n
        on d.NoOfUnit >= n.n
order by d.ID
        ,d.ITEM;
```

#### Output

| ID | ITEM | QTY |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | A | 1 |
| 1 | A | 1 |
| 2 | B | 1 |
| 3 | C | 1 |
| 3 | C | 1 |
| 3 | C | 1 |